# get the variable name passed to a function in C

Tags: c

I am writing a demo program to print address of the variable. To make the code look cleaner I have created a header file in which the function is declared(ex.pointer.h) and a C file for calling that function(ex. main.c). I want to print the address of the variable with the variable name called in main.c

main.c:

```
#include "pointer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int var=40;
    printAddress(var);
}
```

pointer.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *p;
#define getName(var) #var

void printAddress(int a){
    p=&a;
    printf("Address of variable %s is %p\n",getName(a),p);
}
```

I tried using macros but it prints`Address of variable a is 0x7fff2424407c` which is not the expected output`Address of variable var is 0x7fff2424407c`. Can anyone please tell me what changes I should make and please explain.

Comment: Impossible. The names are for compiler and linker only, not for runtime. You may parse debug data to extract name corresponding to address, but it is another question.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. Can you please tell how I can parse debug data to extract the name

Comment: C or C++? They're different languages with different idiomatic solutions. Please pick one.

Comment: In C++, variables can be passed to functions by reference.  This is why the language choice matters; your answer may be different depending on the language.

Comment: I have been thinking this for long though.

Comment: C @JonathonReinhart

Comment: Debuggers have access to variable names.  If you want the names of variables, you'll need a table of `<address, name>`, provided that the variable is not a local variable.  Local variables may not have an address; the compiler can choose to store them in a register or drop (remove) them.  Register variables usually don't have memory addresses.  Local variables may have temporary locations in the stack that may get overwritten by another function or future local variable allocations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't print the address of a variable using function like you've shown. The reason is that `a` is local variable, which has a different identity than the variable whose *value* you passed to `printAddress`.

You also can't get the name, because the name doesn't exist in that context.

However, you could use a macro:

```c
#define printAddress(x)    printf("Address of variable %s is %p\n", #x, &x)
```

Note that `#` here is the stringification operator of the preprocessor; it turns a token into a C string literal (effectively just adding quotes around the token).

Full example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define printAddress(x)    printf("Address of variable %s is %p\n", #x, &x)

int main(void)
{
    int foo;
    printAddress(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about passing the variable by reference?  Does the reference have the same address as the "refererrant" in the `main` function?

Comment: The address of a variable can be printed by `std::cout`, by using a `static_cast` to `void *`.  The `operator<<(void *)` has been coded to print addresses. :-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That's C++, this question is C.

Comment: Sorry, but it was originally tagged with the C++ language tag.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Didn't notice that. But the use of stdio usually indicates C, which is presumably why someone removed the C++ tag.

Comment: The title said "in C" and the question said "a C file" -- I think that's sufficient evidence for @paxdiablo to make the change.

Comment: Yes, that was basically my reasoning. I particularly like the C tag info: *C is distinct from C++ and it should not be combined with the C++ tag absent a rational reason.*

Comment: I am really sorry for C++ tag

Answer (score 3):

A macro can prepare the name and address of a variable before passing it to the actual function. Do not do this in production code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void printAddress(char *name, void *address)
{
    printf("The address of %s is %p.\n", name, address);
}


#define printAddress(x) printAddress(#x, &(x))


int main(void)
{
    int var = 40;
    printAddress(var);
}
```

Comment: Why not do this?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Playing games with macros leads to confusion for future developers and to bugs.

Comment: Sir Can you please explain what does this means:A macro can prepare the name and address of a variable before passing it to the actual function. Do not do this in production code

Comment: There are a great many dangerous things you can do in C but that's not really a reason not to do them, provided you understand and mitigate (preferably totally) the potential impact.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using macros but it printsAddress of variable a is 0x7fff2424407c which is not the expected outputAddress of variable var is 0x7fff2424407c.

At the place where you call the `getName` the variable name is **a**. There is no way to track back that you have passed a value that has been referenced by variable `var` before. This is because, as far as the compiler is concerned, you do not pass a "name" of a variable but it value - in this case an integer - which for the purpose of havg the code human readable is names **a** in the `printAddress` function body.

Now, the only way to achieve what you want is to get rid of the function and implement the whole thing as a macro.

Alternatively, you could create a template class that would keep the value and a name of the variable as a member variables but that would be an overkill. If you need this for debugging purposes then please consider using debugger such as gdb (or better cgdb) - it would be a much better choice.

Answer (score 1):

At the place where you call the getName the variable name is a. There is no way to track back that you have passed a value that has been referenced by variable var before. This is because, as far as the compiler is concerned, you do not pass a "name" of a variable but it value - in this case an integer - which for the purpose of havg the code human readable is names a in the printAddress function body.

Now, the only way to achieve what you want is to get rid of the function and implement the whole thing as a macro.

Alternatively, you could create a template class that would keep the value and a name of the variable as a member variables but that would be an overkill. If you need this for debugging purposes then please consider using debugger such as gdb (or better cgdb) - it would be a much better choice.